# Redirigir a página al seleccionar en ComboBox Submit

Tags: php, javascript, html5, mysqli, combobox

Hola actualmente tengo este problema que no me deja avanzar. Cuento con un pequeño formulario basicamente con dos ComboBox de opciones SI y NO.
Me gustaría saber como puedo lograr que al momento de que el usuario selecciono del primer combobox la opción SI y al precionar el botón lo redirija a una pagina en especifico, al igual al precionar en el segundo Combobox SI y despues el botón lo redirija a otra pagina distinta. Lo mismo pasaría si selecciona NO en ambos combobox. ESPERO SEA CLARO CON LO QUE BUSCO Y AGRADEZO SU AYUDA.

```
<form >
<label>Te gusta el cine?:</label>
    <select class='form-control' name='CBC'>
        <option value='si' checked=''>SI</option>
        <option value='no'>NO</option>
    </select>

<label>Te gusta Leer?</label>
    <select class='form-control' name='CBL'>
        <option value='si' checked=''>SI</option>
        <option value='no'>NO</option>
    </select>

    <button type='submit'>Enviar Respuestas</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías realizar es lo siguiente. Te doy un ejemplo para que tengas una idea

En HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male" id="opcion1" >
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female" id="opcion2" >

<input type="submit" onClick="redirect()">
```

En JS:

```
function redirect()
{
   if(document.getElementById("opcion1").checked == true)
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
   else if(document.getElementById("opcion2").checked == true)
        window.location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';        
}
```

Con PHP de otra manera

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="option1" value="1" /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="option2" value="1" /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="option3" id="option3" value="1" /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="option4" id="option4" value="1" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if($_POST['option1'] == 1 ){
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
}
elseif($_POST['option2'] == 1 ){
    header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com");
}
elseif($_POST['option3'] == 1 ){
    header("Location: http://www.bing.com");
}
elseif($_POST['option4'] == 1 ){
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com");
}
else {
    header("Location: http://www.domain1.com");
} 
?>
```

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no me redirecciona, supongo que debe ser por que los Combobox los tengo dentro de un formulario <form action="lamismapagina.php"></form> estas etiquetas tienen la acción dentro de la misma página dónde estoy haciendo el proyecto, me recomiendas crear un archivo .js exterior y llamarlo desde el action del form? es decir <form action='redirect.js'></form>

Comment: edité mi respuesta, probá hacerlo con php, generalmente dejo un archivo php aparte para que realize las acciones de los forms

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo por tu aportación, eres muy bueno.

Comment: cualquier otra cosa comentame, saludos!